# Tikz drawing technique

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{geometry}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
    
 \begin{document}

 \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,cap=round]
 \draw[style=help lines,step=1cm, dotted] (-0.9,-0.9) grid (9.9,7.9);

\draw[<->] (-0.9,0) -- (9.9,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[<->] (0,-0.9) -- (0,7.9) node[above] {$y$};
    
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (4,3);
    \coordinate (A1) at (4,0);
\coordinate (B) at (8,6);
    \coordinate (B1) at (8,0);

    \draw[thick,black,->,shorten >=-1.5cm] (O)--(B);
    
    \draw[fill] (O) circle (2pt) node[below left]{$O$};
    \draw[fill,blue] (A) circle (2pt) node[right=3pt] {\large $(x^{'},y^{'})$};
    \node at (A) [above] {$\textcolor{blue}{P^{'}}$};
    \draw[fill,red] (B) circle (2pt) node[right=3pt]{\large $(x,y)$};
    \node at (B) [above]{$\textcolor{red}{P}$};
    
    \draw[black] (4,.3)--(3.7,.3)--(3.7,0);
    \draw[black] (8,.3)--(7.7,.3)--(7.7,0);
    
    \draw[dashed,blue,thick] (A) -- (A1) node[below] {\large $A^{'}$};
    \draw[dashed,red,thick]  (B) -- (B1) node[below] {\large $A^{'}$};

    \draw pic["\textcolor{black}{\large $\theta$}", draw=black,thick, ->, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
{angle=A1--O--B};

    \end{tikzpicture} 
   \end{center}
   \end{document}

   outputs
```

[image]

```
 I'm trying to finish it to look like
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use relative coordinates to place what is missing. Since OP' is in the direction of (4,3), the perpendicular vector will be in the direction of (-3,4).

Add the following line to your code

```
\draw (O) ++ (-3*0.03,4*0.03) --++ (-3*0.25,4*0.25);
\draw (A) ++ (-3*0.03,4*0.03) --++ (-3*0.075,4*0.075);
\draw (B) ++ (-3*0.03,4*0.03) --++ (-3*0.25,4*0.25);

\draw[blue,<->,>=latex] (O) ++ (-3*0.07,4*0.07) -- node[midway,above] {$r^{'}$}++ (4,3);
\draw[red,<->,>=latex] (O) ++ (-3*0.2,4*0.2) -- node[midway,above] {$r$}++ (8,6);
```

The first three lines draw the black delimiter lines. The scale value (0.03, 0.25, etc.) are approximate. You can play with them to ajust the position of the lines.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
    
 \begin{document}

 \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,cap=round]
 \draw[style=help lines,step=1cm, dotted] (-0.9,-0.9) grid (9.9,7.9);

\draw[<->] (-0.9,0) -- (9.9,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[<->] (0,-0.9) -- (0,7.9) node[above] {$y$};
    
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (4,3);
    \coordinate (A1) at (4,0);
\coordinate (B) at (8,6);
    \coordinate (B1) at (8,0);

    \draw[thick,black,->,shorten >=-1.5cm] (O)--(B);
    
    \draw[fill] (O) circle (2pt) node[below left]{$O$};
    \draw[fill,blue] (A) circle (2pt) node[right=3pt] {\large $(x^{'},y^{'})$};
    \node at (A) [above] {$\textcolor{blue}{P^{'}}$};
    \draw[fill,red] (B) circle (2pt) node[right=3pt]{\large $(x,y)$};
    \node at (B) [above]{$\textcolor{red}{P}$};
    
    \draw[black] (4,.3)--(3.7,.3)--(3.7,0);
    \draw[black] (8,.3)--(7.7,.3)--(7.7,0);
    
    \draw[dashed,blue,thick] (A) -- (A1) node[below] {\large $A^{'}$};
    \draw[dashed,red,thick]  (B) -- (B1) node[below] {\large $A^{'}$};

    \draw pic["\textcolor{black}{\large $\theta$}", draw=black,thick, ->, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=A1--O--B};

    \draw (O) ++ (-3*0.03,4*0.03) --++ (-3*0.25,4*0.25);
    \draw (A) ++ (-3*0.03,4*0.03) --++ (-3*0.075,4*0.075);
    \draw (B) ++ (-3*0.03,4*0.03) --++ (-3*0.25,4*0.25);

    \draw[blue,<->,>=latex] (O) ++ (-3*0.07,4*0.07) -- node[midway,above] {$r^{'}$}++ (4,3);
    \draw[red,<->,>=latex] (O) ++ (-3*0.2,4*0.2) -- node[midway,above] {$r$}++ (8,6);

    \end{tikzpicture} 
   \end{center}
   \end{document}
```